# Toast Widget on Android 2.3.3

Tags: android, toast

Hi I have a problem with my app. When I create a new project for Android 2.2 or lower my app works fine and my toast shows on screen but when I create a new project for 2.3 or 2.3.3 with the same code the toast does not appear at all. Also I have added the Textview update with in the main OnCreate thread but still me textview does not update. I need to solve the toast issue mainly though.
thanks

```
public class Location extends Activity  {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
static String Text;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
    final TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    lm.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {



    private final String TAG = null;

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(android.location.Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       Text = "My current location is: " + "Latitud = " + location.getLatitude() + "Longitud = "   + location.getLongitude(); 
       Context context = getApplicationContext();
       int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
       Toast.makeText(context, Text, duration).show();
            tv.setText(Text);
        try
        {
            File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File gps = new File(root, "log.txt");




        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(
                new FileWriter(gps,true)) ;

        out.write(Text);
        out.write("");
        out.close();

        }


        catch (IOException e) {


            Log.e(TAG, "Could not write file " + e.getMessage());

        }
    }
```

Comment: i edited code to include .show for toast but no difference.

Answer (score 3):

You have to call show() on the Toast.

```
Toast.makeText(context, Text, duration).show();
```

All you are doing is creating the Toast and not showing it.

The TextView update might be failing because of an Exception.

Comment: oh god ha ha I added .show  (must of deleted when copy and pasting) but still it dont show up. what kind of exception could cause textview not to update.

Comment: You are updating the TextView in a try block where you are also trying to write out a file.

Comment: I moved the TextView update after the IO Exception block and it still dont update and my toast still does not show. Its driving me crazy as the toast works fine on 2.2 or lower.